# Is it possible to use the autocomplete option in an input field without the map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have a search field that wont use the map.

**html**

`<input type="text" ui-gmap-search-box ng-model="GeneralFactory.Location" events="searchbox.events" placeholder="Location" class="form-control input-lg">`

**app.js**

```
app.config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (GoogleMapApi) {
    GoogleMapApi.configure({
        //  key: 'your api key',
        //    v: '3.20',
        libraries: 'places'
    });
}]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        searchbox: {
            events:{
                places_changed: function (searchBox) {}
            }
        },
        options: {
            scrollwheel: false
        }
    });

    GoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        maps.visualRefresh = true;
    });
}]);
```

All I want is an autocompletion of location. But this throws  following error

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'uiGmapGoogleMap', required by directive 'uiGmapSearchBox', can't be found!

I think this is because I havent put searchbox inside the map. As I dont want to use the map what can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who stumbles across this, the answer can be found here. https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1828

Short answer is that it (currently) can't be done.